# Why Monitor.Wait and PulseAll in .NET 4.0 is not working

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In our Legacy project we were using following code for asynchronous operations:

```
public interface IAsyncOperation
{
    OperationToken Token { get; }
    bool IsCompleted { get; }
    Exception Exception { get; }
    bool Wait(int timeout);
}

/// <summary>
/// Asynchronous operation that may be executed on a separate thread.
/// IsCompleted and Exception would be synchronized after invoking Wait.
/// </summary>
public abstract class AsyncOperation : IAsyncOperation
{
    protected readonly object CompletionLock = new object();
    private volatile bool isCompleted; // volatile in order not to change the order of writing Exception and Result

    protected AsyncOperation(bool isCompleted = false)
    {
        IsCompleted = isCompleted;
        Token = OperationToken.New();
    }

    public OperationToken Token { get; protected set; }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return isCompleted; }
        protected set { isCompleted = value; }
    }

    public Exception Exception { get; protected set; }

    public bool Wait(int timeout)
    {
        if (!IsCompleted)
        {
            lock (CompletionLock)
            {
                if (!IsCompleted)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(CompletionLock, timeout);
                }
            }
        }

        return IsCompleted;
    }

    protected void Complete()
    {
        RequireNotCompleted();
        lock (CompletionLock)
        {
            RequireNotCompleted();
            IsCompleted = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(CompletionLock);
        }
    }

    protected void RequireNotCompleted()
    {
        if (IsCompleted)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation was already completed");
        }
    }

    protected void Complete(Exception exception)
    {
        RequireNotCompleted();
        lock (CompletionLock)
        {
            RequireNotCompleted();
            Exception = exception;
            IsCompleted = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(CompletionLock);
        }
    }
}
```

It was always working fine. After migrating the project to .NET 4.5.1 it looks like we have following problems:

1. We made a `Wait(Timeout.Inifinte)` and we know that an operation has completed but the thread with `Wait` is waiting forever... if we set a timeout than it always leave the method after the timeout
2. In profiler we see that probably `Complete()` waits to enter the lock - is `Monitor.Wait` not giving back the lock?

[image]

Here is also the implementation of `AsyncCommand` which is executed in a worker thread:

```
internal class AsyncCommand : AsyncOperation
{
    private readonly Action<OperationToken> command;

    public AsyncCommand(Action<OperationToken> command)
    {
        command.ThrowIfNull("command");
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        RequireNotCompleted();
        try
        {
            command(Token);
            Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Complete(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you see any problem with the following code?
What can cause these problems?

**Closed**
The above implementation is correct. We had some problems connected with .NET remoting...

Comment: Hard to make the call without knowing how this is used.  The high execution time for Complete() suggests a lock convoy problem.  Where PulseAll() releases a horde of threads, all trying to acquire the lock again.  The volatile bool is questionable, replace with a ManualResetEventSlim.